# Xamarin.Mac image animation is not working

Tags: macos, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

I want to show on my page animation gif, image showing but without animation.

Code is simple:

```
<Image Source="{extensions:ImageResource DesktopClient.Resources.preloader@24.gif}" IsAnimationPlaying="True" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

Can't find any working solution.

Comment: Googling for issues related to xamarin image gifs, it might be more reliable to store it in an [Asset Catalog Image Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/app-fundamentals/image#adding-images-to-an-asset-catalog-image-set), instead of as a resource. See also [this github example](https://github.com/jfversluis/AnimatedGifForms). That doesn't have mac, but mac should be similar to ios, AFAIK.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried to do same like in this example https://github.com/jfversluis/AnimatedGifForms in Xamarin.Mac but not worked, image shown but not playing

Comment: Would you mind sharing us a baisc, minimal project to test ? You can upload it to github and attach the link here .

Comment: Ok, I have create a small sample https://github.com/aspnetman/AnimatedImageApp

Answer (score 0):

I test it on my side, and it did not work either,
As official doucment says:

> This is a Preview, so you should expect that not everything is
> production ready. Below are a few things you may encounter as you add
> macOS to your projects:

So I recommend you to post an issue on github :https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Comment: Thank you will post issue